# Primefaces p:celleditor celledit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm implementing a p:dataTable component, based on the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf)

The code is:

```xml
<p:dataTable
    id="newDataTable"
    editable="true"
    editMode="cell"
    var="item"
    value="#{myBean.listNewDataTable}">

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{myBean.newCellEditListener}" update="@this"/>
    <p:column width="150" >
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:inputText value="#{item.description}" readonly="true"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{item.id}" style="width: 90%;">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.productsMap.entrySet()}" var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    -- More Data --
</p:dataTable>
```

And the backing bean method:

```
public void newCellEditListener(CellEditEvent event){
    ... Some work here ...
}
```

When the value on the editable cell is changed, the p:cellEditor works as expected.

The problem is:

> When the value on the editable cell remains unchanged, the p:cellEditor shows the item.id when it should actually be showing the item.description.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need additional configuration?

I have been googling for a tip or an answer, without success.

**UPDATE**

Same problem persists on the following code:

```xml
<p:column headerText="Money" width="150" >
    <p:cellEditor >
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:inputText value="#{actual.money}" readonly="true">
                <f:convertNumber type="currency" />
            </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{actual.money}">
            </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

The value on the backing bean its the same for input and output, the difference between each other should be the 'currency' format.

**UPDATE**

As a workaround I used "p:commandButton" to update the Datatable.

```xml
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" update="newDataTable" value="Update" />
```

The app is running on:

- Primefaces 3.5
- Primefaces Extensions 0.7.1
- Mojarra 2.1.22
- Tomcat 7

Thanks for your help.
Kind regards.

Comment: Why are you using an input component for the `output` facet? Why not an `<h:outputText/>`?

Comment: @kolossus Actually, the user wants to see an input text instead

Answer (score 0):

Values in output and input should be the same. Try to fix that.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Should it be the same value for input and output? I mean, Should it be without format or business logic?

Comment: What do you mean by the same problem? Which value now you can see?

Comment: On the second case, when cell remains unchanged it shows the 'actual.money' value without format. When cell its changed everything works as expected. Is this the default behavior? Am I wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have yu tried putting `h:outputText` inside `<f:facet name="output">` instead `<h:inputText>`?

Comment: Actually, the user wants to see an input text instead. Anyway, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I changed the component as suggested but it doesn't work. I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue reported and fixed on the Primefaces issue site: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6116

I downloaded the 4.0.RC1 and I do see the issue as being resolved as reported but there are some major differences in 4.0 versus 3.5 so I'm going to be waiting for 3.5.15 to be released.